# Single SQLstatement for many INSERTs

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, Name varchar(100), [Key] int, primary key (ID))
INSERT INTO #Test (Name, [Key]) values ('Ian',1)
INSERT INTO #Test (Name, [Key]) values ('Iain',1)
INSERT INTO #Test (Name, [Key]) values ('Eon',1)
INSERT INTO #Test (Name, [Key]) values ('Mark',2)
INSERT INTO #Test (Name, [Key]) values ('Steven',2)
```

and the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test2 (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, Name varchar(100), primary key (ID))
INSERT INTO #Test2 (Name) values ('Graham')
INSERT INTO #Test2 (Name) values ('William')
INSERT INTO #Test2 (Name) values ('Neil')
INSERT INTO #Test2 (Name) values ('Calum')
INSERT INTO #Test2 (Name) values ('Wayne')
```

I want to INSERT everything from #Test2 into #Test.  I want each record in #Test2 to have a unique Key in #Test.  In affect I want this to happen:

```
INSERT INTO #Test (Name, [Key]) VALUES ('Graham', 3)
INSERT INTO #Test (Name, [Key]) VALUES ('William', 4)
INSERT INTO #Test (Name, [Key]) VALUES ('Calum', 5)
INSERT INTO #Test (Name, [Key]) VALUES ('Wayne', 6)
```

There are millions of records in #Test and #Test2.

Is it possible to do all the INSERTS with a single SQL statement or do I have to use a cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just new numbers that are higher than the max. key that exists? This should work:

```
declare @maxkey int
select @maxkey = max([Key]) from Test

insert into Test (Name, [Key]) 
select Name, row_number () over (order by (select null)) + @maxkey
from Test2
```

This just fetches the max. key and uses row_number to add numbers to the rows coming from Test2.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4aa2f/1)

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some logic like this:

```
insert into #Test
select Name, ((select max([Key]) from #Test) + ID) as [Key]
from #Test2
order by ID asc;
```

Here is my Fiddle example: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58c93/6)